# Need a generic destructor fro deleting scalar as well as array of pointers

Tags: c++

I have a class that is called to release the memory as below:

```
template<typename T>
class mymemrel
{
    T ptr;
public:
    mymemrel()
    {
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    mymemrel(T ptrArg)
    {
        ptr = ptrArg;
    }
    void memoryInit(T ptrArg)
    {
        ptr = ptrArg;
    }
    ~mymemrel()
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

in the destructor `~mymemrel()` I need to handle both the freeing up of memory for scalar as well array of pointers(i.e. delete ptr if its scalar delete[] ptr if its array) how can this be achieved?

Comment: By specialization? Look up how `std::unique_ptr` is defined in the standard, which solves the exact same problem.

Comment: The easy way: do not use raw pointers or arrays, and stop worrying about `delete`. `std::vector` loves you. Not so easy way: start by trying to determine somehow which kind of pointer you have, to a single object or to an array. Who has this information?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which kind of pointer, is there a way to find whether the pointer is to single object or to an array.

Comment: No there is not. You must know it by some other means.

Answer (score 1):

As kerrek suggested, use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(1));  //manages a int
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]); //manages entire array of ints
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have something of type `T*`, you can not actually know how it was allocated, hence you can not destroy it properly in generic way. It is not only matter of `new` or `new[]`, objects could be allocated with malloc, OS-dependent allocator, object pools, etc.

Depending on your goals, `std::unique_ptr` might be the best solution, it can handle only `new/delete` and `new[]/delete[]`, but in most cases it is sufficient.

Also, std::shared_prt is an option, you can specify how to deallocate objects:

```
//c++11
std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], []( int *p ) { delete[] p; } );
```

If you want to have your own memory management system, consider allocating and deallocating objects at the same place.